# How to get a list of all pages where document, page appears in content across the site collection

Tags: site-collection, document

I would like to ask, is it possible to use some script (maybe Powershell), or anything which can help to find page or document within the entire Site Collection so it gives you the complete list of pages where the particular link (of document, page) is used in the content.

Thanks.